# Is this an example of a good use of inheritence?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I've been reading that inheritance is usually bad code design.  Despite that, I'll sometimes inherit from a List or a BindingList of a business object.  Here's a simple business object I might use:

```
public class RowType
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Sales { get; set; }
}
```

Here are two options for an object that holds a collection of `RowType`s:

```
//Option A: "Has-A" relationship
public class RowHolderType
{
    private readonly BindingList<RowType> _rows;
    public BindingList<RowType> Rows { get { return this._rows; } }
    public RowHolderType() { this._rows = new BindingList<RowType>(); }
}

//Option B: "Is-A" relationship
public class RowHolderType : BindingList<RowType>
{
    public RowHolderType() : base() { }
    public RowHolderType(IList<RowType> list) : base(list) { }
}
```

I usually go with Option B.  I find that I usually have to write less code when I go with Option B. I normally use a class like this for displaying a list of editable data in a WPF window.

Is there some hidden drawback to using Option B?  Or can I go on happily extending `BindingList<T>`s?

EDIT: Adding an example.

I mentioned in a comment that I might use Option B at times when I want better control over the notifications that `BindingList` can send.  I might want to indicate that I'm starting a batch of updates, and then later finishing the same batch of updates.  To do that, I would inherit BindingList and add some functionality:

```
public class RowTypeHolder : BindingList<RowType>
{
    public event BeforeListChangedEventHandler BeforeListChanged;
    public delegate void BeforeListChangedEventHandler(RowTypeHolder sender, RowTypeHolderEventArgs e);

    public event AfterListChangedEventHandler AfterListChanged;
    public delegate void AfterListChangedEventHandler(RowTypeHolder sender, RowTypeHolderEventArgs e);

    public void OnBeforeListChanged(RowTypeHolderEventArgs.ChangeType change, string eventName)
    {
        if (this.BeforeListChanged != null)
            this.BeforeListChanged(this, new RowTypeHolderEventArgs(change, 0, eventName));
    }

    public void OnAfterListChanged(RowTypeHolderEventArgs.ChangeType change, int numChanges, string eventName)
    {
        if (this.AfterListChanged != null)
            this.AfterListChanged(this, new RowTypeHolderEventArgs(change, numChanges, eventName));
    }
}
```

The caller is responsible for sending the `BeforeListChanged` and `AfterListChanged` notifications.  I haven't tried this with a "Has-A" type relationship, but I assume that that code would be uglier.  (Note that I left out the definitions for `RowTypeHolderEventArgs` and `RowTypeHolderEventArgs.ChangeType`.  I don't think it's important for this example.)

Comment: `I've been reading that inheritance is usually bad code design.` where? This is nonsense. Option B would usually be your best bet. If there's anything bad in your design, it's calling your class `RowType` which tells me nothing about what it actually is.

Comment: It depends. Why are you making such a class in the first place?

Comment: Inheritance is a key concept in OOP. The only bad inheritance is diamond inheritance.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with either option A or B. They implement different needs, though with overlap. I suggest looking for an opportunity where A is better, to build your skill set, but otherwise keep on as you are.

Comment: Also, [collection classes should end in `Collection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182244.aspx)

Comment: I suspect the post is referring to guidelines such as "prefer composition over inheritance" which, while valuable, are often overstated...

Comment: __Option C:__ Just use  `BindingList<RowType>` and no wrapper or inherited class. Only when you do have a good reason for either one (extra members and functionality) can you make a decision.

Comment: There are situations where composition (Option A) makes more sense than inheritance, but only when you need it - generally when you need to "inherit" from more than one class. In the normal world, when you're simply extending an existing class, inheritance is fine.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, I do that sometimes as well. Sometimes I like to have better control over the notifications that BindingList sends.  I have added events that allow a caller to signal that it's about to start or end a batch of updates to the list.  In that way, if I have an operation that runs better with a batch of RowTypes than several individual RowTypes, I can handle that situation.

Comment: @user2023861 - add an example to the question. It probably points to HAS-A.

Comment: Inheritance is used where you feel you need to use an existing object as the base object, but feel the need to override or extend certain methods or properties belonging to that class. Inheritance is a key aspect of OOP. Why create a new Object from scratch when you dont have too? its over engineering.

Answer (score 0):

Without more context, it's hard for me to decide which one I prefer more, I normally like to structure the code after my mental model of the problem.

Ask yourself the question:

**IS** `RowHolderType` a `BindingList<RowType>` in the rhetorical sense?  If it is, than yes, inheritance is 100% appropriate.

Comment: That's not the only thing you need to ask yourself though.  For example, was the intended base class written with inheritance in mind?  There are lots of classes that really should be `sealed`, but aren't, and the class is written such that it really shouldn't be inherited (because the design just isn't sufficently robust).  If it doesn't provide sufficient means to modify behavior for inheritors as appropriate (for example, having methods be virtual and having protected implementation methods that can be overridden), it may be better to use composition.

Comment: @Sam I am , there is a classic example to dispute the 'Is A' paradigm, a square 'IS a' quadrangular  but should probaly not inherit it.